# Can you chain a function after a transition without it being a part of the transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For instance if I wanted to transition the yAxis domain I can do this

```
this.yAxis
    .transition()
    .call(this.createYAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate( ${this.Axes.Y.offset}, 0 )`);
```

I'd also like to set the text size in the same selection, but I don't want to animate the text size. Is this possible in the same chain? For instance,

```
this.yAxis
    .transition()
    .call(this.createYAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate( ${this.Axes.Y.offset}, 0 )`)
    //I don't want anything past this point to be a part of the transition
  .selectAll('text')
    .style('font-size', '15px');
```

Right now I'm just using two separate calls like so

```
this.yAxis
    .transition()
    .call(this.createYAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate( ${this.Axes.Y.offset}, 0 )`);

this.yAxis.selectAll( 'text')
   .style( 'font-size', '15px' )
```

Comment: you could do : this.yAxis.selectAll( 'text')
   .style( 'font-size', '15px' ).transition().call( this.createYAxis )
    .attr( 'transform', `translate( ${this.Axes.Y.offset}, 0 )` )

Comment: Once I `selectAll(' text ')` the selection is no longer for my yAxis though, it's for the text of the yAxis. calling `this.createYAxis` on the text elements of the axis won't work.......

Comment: As soon as you call .transition(), the selection becomes a transition. So, the answer to your question is No. You have to do selectAll text before transition using two separate calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of D3 **v4** there is a method [`transition.selection()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_selection) which

> Returns the selection corresponding to this transition.

By means of this method you can break free from the transition started beforehand by `selection.transition()`. This enables continued method chaining acting on the selection instead of the transition.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .range([30, 270]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
  .call(axis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .selection()   // <-- get the selection corresponding to the transition
    .style("font-size", "26px");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question...

> Can you chain a function after a transition without it being a part of the transition?

... is **no**. Once you called the `transition()`, your selection is a transition selection. That's why, for instance, a lot of people get errors when using `.on("click",...)` in a transition selection.

However, you have another question here:

> Is this possible (set the text size) in the same chain?

The answer is **yes**. The most obvious choice is just setting the style before the transition, like this:

```
var gX = svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", "26px")
    .transition()
    //etc...
```

That way, you avoid the situation you described in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405264/can-you-chain-a-function-after-a-transition-without-the-it-being-a-part-of-the-t/47407455#comment81764632_47405264), which is the selection no longer being a selection for the axis.

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .range([30, 270]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .style("font-size", "26px")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .call(axis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

EDIT: another solution is using `on("start", ...)`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .range([30, 270]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .call(axis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .on("start", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("font-size", "30px")
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: "The answer to your question...

Can you chain a function after a transition without it being a part of the transition?
... is no."

You can actually, you write:
.on('end', () => {
   /* code you want to execute at the end of transition '/
})

Comment: @OdinThorsen no, you can't. In your example, the function is technically a part of the transition. Also, it will execute only when the transition **ends**: OP wants the texts that size right when they first appear.

Comment: In what way? it won't be animated like the actual transition is, it will act, as far as I can tell, exactly like a non transition function

Comment: In that case, please add your answer, with a running snippet. I'm curious to see this working!

Comment: I think your solution is correct I just wanted to point out that it **is** possible :p

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong: I'm not being ironic, I'm really curious! Show me that your approach works: post an answer with a running snippet. By the way, it will work with `.on("start", ...)`, but not with `"end"` (see my edit). However, it is technically part of the transition (the `.on` method, not the callback).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example of executing the update **after** the transition, now I don't know why anyone would want to have this particular font change happen after , but I use this all the time when I need to turn something off until the transition ends and **then** turn it back on.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .range([30, 270]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .call(axis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .on('end', () => {
        d3.selectAll( 'text')
       .style( 'font-size', '15px')
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```