# Trouble with storing enter selections containing transitions

Tags: d3.js, selection, transition

If I try to store the following enter selection, I get an error when I try to access it. I don't have a problem if I remove the transition. Why? Are there other restrictions on storing selections? Here is an example:

```
// this works
var enterSel = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data([100, 200, 300])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d)
    .attr("cy", "100")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", "0")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("r", "50");
```

The above appends and transitions three circles to red, as expected, but the `enterSel` variable cannot be used for further modifications:

```
// this doesn't work
enterSel.attr("fill", "green");

Uncaught Error: transition not found       d3.v4.min.js:2 
  at zn (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at Cn (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at qn.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at qn.tween (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at qn.attrTween (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at qn.attr (d3.v4.min.js:2)
  at <anonymous>:1:10
```

I can get around this by doing the transition separately, as follows, but I really want to understand why this is necessary.

```
// this works
var enterSel = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data([100, 200, 300])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d)
    .attr("cy", "100")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", "0");

enterSel.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("r", "50");

enterSel.attr("fill", "green");
```

Comment: This might be how d3 has prototyped things. `selection.transition` has a different prototype than `selection` so things behave slightly differently. If you want to the the difference between the 2 you can use `console.log(d3.selection.prototype)` and `console.log(d3.transition.prototype)`

Comment: A transition doesnt return a selection, it returns a transition, this is why you see the behavior you do.

Comment: These comments help a lot. What's weird is that it sometimes works, that is a stored transition behaves like a selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you chain a function after a transition without it being a part of the transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405264/can-you-chain-a-function-after-a-transition-without-it-being-a-part-of-the-trans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post an answer for the future. A d3 [selection returns a selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) with the `d3.selection.prototype`. A transition on the other hand [returns a transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) with the `d3.transition.prototype`.

```
var enterSel = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data([100, 200, 300])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d)
    .attr("cy", "100")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", "0")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("r", "50");

enterSel.attr("fill", "green");
```

Does not work because `enterSel` is now a transition and has different properties than a selection.

```
var enterSel = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data([100, 200, 300])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d)
    .attr("cy", "100")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", "0");

enterSel.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("r", "50");

enterSel.attr("fill", "green");
```

This one works because `enterSel` is always a selection, which uses the selection prototype. The transition is sectioned away in the second call, but `enterSel` is always the selection of all the circles.

Hopefully this helps clear things up!

Comment: Yes it does. It's an important distinction, yet I haven't seen it made in any of the D3 tutorials I've looked at.